# How do I get a system upgrade for advanced lasers?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

How do I get a system upgrade? I have an advanced laser and adding power doesn't let me use it. It says system upgrade needed. Is a weapons upgrade what I need?

Answer (score 20):

Weapon power usage is detailed in the bottom left of the screen, along with all of your other power indicators, and your currently active weapons are detailed to the right of that on a bar across the bottom of the screen;

[image]

In the above screenshot you will see I have a Heavy Laser 1 with a power requirement of 2, and a Fire Beam with a power requirement of 3, but only a maximum of 4 weapon power. In this instance, I need to upgrade my weapon power to 5 in order to activate both weapons at once.

To upgrade your weapon power, click on the 'SHIP' button at the top of the screen (next to 'JUMP') while not in combat to open up the ship screen and then increase the maximum power available to your weapons;

[image: Ship screen]

It is not possible to exceed the weapon power cap detailed on the ship screen.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to upgrade your weapons system or power down other weapons.  You can see how much you need to upgrade by substracting the number of unused energy bars (black) in your weapons system from the amount of power the weapon draws.